# Can you augment the messages for one of the Apache Camel multicast routes from another route

Tags: apache-camel

I am implementing a customer add scenario. The input is the customer object which needs to be sent to one jms queue to create a customer, and then sequentially to another queue to update the customer with some of the fields not supported by the first system. There's a background sync between two systems so the customer will already exist in the system2 by the time I send the update request. The issue that I am having now is that I need to extract the customer id from the system1 response and augment the customer object for system2 with it. And the route should return that customer id. What's the right way to do that in Camel?

That's what I have now:

```
    from("direct:customerUpdate)
            .multicast(new AggregationStrategy() {
                @Override
                public Exchange aggregate(Exchange oldExchange, Exchange newExchange) {
                    if (oldExchange == null) {
                        return newExchange;
                    }
                    return oldExchange;
                }
            })
            .stopOnException()
            .to("direct:addCustomerSystem1", "direct:updateCustomerSystem2")
            .end();
```

addCustomerSystem1 returns customer id but that doesn't augment the customer object for updateCustomerSystem2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use multicast, but just plain to (eg pipes and filters), or the content enricher. The latter allows you to augment the response from system1 before sending to system2.